# Operator overload doubts

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, operators

I was trying to write some operator overload functions, especially the `<<` operator to use it with a custom class and an `std::ofstream` object, but I was a bit confused by the syntax used in various examples found online. For example, let's consider the `operator<<` overload as a non-member function for a simple custom class:

```
#include <fstream>

class Example {
public:
    int first;
    int second;
};

// I found this kind of operator on the Internet
std::ofstream& operator<< (std::ofstream& out, Example obj) {
    out << obj.first << endl << obj.second;
    return out;
}

int main() {
    Example a={1,2};
    std::ofstream out;
    out.open("test");
    out << a;
    out.close();   
}
```

I don't really get why It should return `std::ofstream&` to work properly. I tried using the following operator

```
void operator<< (std::ofstream& out, Example obj) {
     out << obj.first << endl << obj.second << endl;
}
```

and it worked as well. I mean, can't `out << obj;` be interpreted as `operator<< (out , obj);` ? Why does it have to return something since I'm passing a reference to the `std::ofstream` object?

The same doubt arose when I was trying to write an `operator=` overload as a member function for a custom class, as the simple example that follows

```
class Custom{
public:
    int up;
    int down;

    Custom& operator= (Custom a) {
         up=a.up;
         down=a.down;
         return *this;
    }
};
```

I used the copy-swap idiom for the assignment operator, so don't mind the operator definition too much, it's just an example. Again, writing

```
Custom obj1, obj2;
obj1 = obj2;
```

since I can interpret `obj1 = obj2;` as `obj1.operator=(obj2)`, why is the return type `Custom&` required instead of `void`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to chain `operator<<`s together, you have to use a return type (better `std::ostream&` than `std::ofstream&`, so you can use it for `std::cout` and like, too).

```
out << a << b;
(out << a) << b;
^^^^^^^^^^
lhs has to be a stream
```

For assignment operator, the reason is essentially the same. C++ syntax allows you to write many expressions requiring the return type, for example this:

```
Custom obj1, obj2, obj3;
(obj1 = obj2) + obj3 ... // assign obj2 to obj1 and work with that...
```

Comment: Isn't `(obj1=obj2)+obj3` supposed to be `(obj1=obj2)=obj3` ? anyway thank you, this was helpful

Comment: @luigi I just chose `operator+` (which isn't defined in your code) instead of `operator=`. Doesn't matter. Chaining `=` together might be more common, though.

Comment: oh ok, though you meant something like what @songyuanyao wrote beneath.

Answer (score 1):

Returning a reference allows you to chain the operators, like

```
std::cout << e1 << e2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Return a *reference* instead of `void`, make it possible to write like

```
out << obj1 << obj2 << obj3;
```

For `operator=`, you can write

```
obj1=obj2=obj3;
```

Comment: That's clear now, hadn't even considered the chaining possibility. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can write somthing like `cout << "First operand" << "Second operand"` because first operand returns reference to `ostream` and second operand works with this reference.
`operator=` works same way. You can write `a = b = c`, but also you can put it inside `if (a = b)` or `while (a = b)`. This can make your code shorter, but is a little dangerous.